# NFC Tap and Pay Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, nfc, secure-element

I was researching to find if there is a way currently to receive a broadcast event when someone changes default payment app in `Tap & Pay` option inside settings

[image]

The article related to this which i found was https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#ACTION_PREFERRED_PAYMENT_CHANGED
which will be added in Android R.

> Is there any other way an android app can detect on its launch whether its the default app set in `Tap and Pay` Option?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for this here

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce#CheckIfDefault

```
 val isAppNFCDefault = cardEmulationManager.isDefaultServiceForCategory(
        ComponentName(
            this@MainActivity,
            MyHostApduService::class.java
        ), CardEmulation.CATEGORY_PAYMENT
    )
```